# Internet Explorer 8 problems with CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have problems with only **Internet Explorer 8**.

I don't know why i add the link of the website i do (I'm newbie):

[Website](http://www.premiosfundacionaffinity.org)
If you click "Candidaturas" in IE8, you will see the text are broken, the styles doesn't work, in IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari.. works well... and i don't know why.

```
div#candidaturas div#content div#columna h8 {
   margin : 0;
   padding : 0;
   text-align : left;
   font-family : Arial;
   font-size : 11px;
   font-variant : normal;
   color : #555;
}

div#candidaturas div#content div#columna h7 {
   text-align : left;
   font-family : Arial;
   font-size : 14px;
   font-weight : bold;
   font-variant : normal;
   color : #ff6b00;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank you all!

Comment: I would change the way you style the elements. Try `#id` instead of `div#id`, it's a better practice and works faster. I would also recommend to avoid such long chaining of three ids... are you sure that `#columna h6` will not work? Also try `font: bold 14px Arial, sans-serif;` instead of dividing them into separate properties :)

Comment: I will prove what you say. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no such headings as `h7` and `h8`. Only `h1`-`h6`. IE8 and IE7 don't understand unknown elements and do not style them.

Comment: I will prove what you say. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can't have multiple div with the same id.

You should use class *.columna* instead of id *#columna*.

This will solve your problem, and others potential futur problems.

Comment: This is true, but is not the only problem.

Comment: I will clear the codes in advance, i add a note on my head to don't do the mistake again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is likely not recognizing `h7` and `h8` tags because they are not a standard. Only up to `h6` is standard. Also you have multiple Divs with the same ID. Divs have to have unique identifiers. Classes can have multiple instances.

Comment: I guess I should have refreshed sooner and I wouldn't be repeating others. Sorry!